# Belated unemployment benefits: Is it possible to apply after a year out of work?

Tags: united-states, benefits, unemployment, application-process

I was laid off last year in May but never bothered to apply for unemployment benefits then because I have a Green Card (permanent resident) and presumed the benefits are only applicable for US citizens

I am still looking for a job. So I was wondering if I can apply for unemployment benefits now and if possible, could I collect some benefits for the period from when I was laid off until now?

Any sort of clarification is greatly appreciated.

Comment: What state are you in? Unemployment insurance differs by state.

Answer (score 3):

1. Green card holders are eligible for unemployment insurance.
2. You are not entitled to retroactive claims unless non-payment was a result of unemployment office activity (e.g., non-payment during the period taken to assess your eligibility, delay between government act to extend and payments made, etc). Having said this, you need to approach your unemployment office and speak with a rep. State laws differ across the country, and only your local office will be able to tell you exactly what you are entitled to.